# autoconf AC_CHECK_* for extern struct *

Tags: pointers, struct, autoconf, extern

I am looking for an AC_CHECK_* function that let's me change a behavior in my code depending on whether pppd/pppd.h contains

```
extern struct notifier *ipv6_up_notifier;
```

which was added recently. It is actually provided in pppd/ipc6cp.h:

```
struct notifier *ipv6_up_notifier = NULL;
```

I have tried with

```
AC_CHECK_DECLS(notifier *ipv6_up_notifier,,, [#include <pppd/pppd.h>])
AC_CHECK_DECLS(extern notifier *ipv6_up_notifier,,, [#include <pppd/pppd.h>])
AC_CHECK_DECLS(struct notifier *ipv6_up_notifier,,, [#include <pppd/pppd.h>])
AC_CHECK_DECLS(extern struct notifier *ipv6_up_notifier,,, [#include <pppd/pppd.h>])
```

but all this leads to

```
checking whether notifier *ipv6_up_notifier is declared... no
```

when ./configure'ing. Is it at all possible to check for extern's?

Comment: I haven't tested it, but have you tried giving just the variable name, i.e. AC_CHECK_DECL([ipv6_up_notifier], ...) ?

Comment: Yes. Stupid me. If you add it as answer instead of a comment, I will accept that answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, the first argument is variable name (without type):

```
AC_CHECK_DECLS([ipv6_up_notifier], [], [], [#include <pppd/pppd.h>])
```